# Docker Compose - stuck on Sending Auth Config

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a pretty straight forward app I'm building. I'm trying to go from a manual input command to using docker compose. I'm stuck in the build when using docker compose. It seems to work fine if I `docker build .`

I have seen other people suggesting a `.dockerignore` to exclude large files and that it can take time to upload, but my entire repo (including .git) is 2.58 MB and my internet speed is clocking 590Mbps down and 600 Mbps up per fast.com.

Here is my branch https://github.com/joshuarlowry/Kiddo-Lullaby/tree/docker-compose

## Result of Docker Build

```
PS D:\Development\KiddoLullaby\app> docker build .
[+] Building 21.5s (11/11) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                          0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 597B                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8-alpine                                                                                                                                                                          1.3s 
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8-alpine@sha256:60a24db20ad0121b3440681ded50a75b762ceb9cb0855847a4b25d291e9de8c2                                                                                                                    9.3s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.8-alpine@sha256:60a24db20ad0121b3440681ded50a75b762ceb9cb0855847a4b25d291e9de8c2                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => => sha256:7678dd7631a2820af5d8aec5e27200b7b3f863f1632a524409fecc4acd2e17e5 280.79kB / 280.79kB                                                                                                                                            0.4s 
 => => sha256:4c6139ab40d87d329213433884ea0774ec3d13c9df656ecee4dfe2e29aaa0ef9 11.33MB / 11.33MB                                                                                                                                              7.6s 
 => => sha256:60a24db20ad0121b3440681ded50a75b762ceb9cb0855847a4b25d291e9de8c2 1.65kB / 1.65kB                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => sha256:fa6434c43f6922aaa7b0ed75a3ddc6e45360001d764965b4be27e057777fc072 1.37kB / 1.37kB                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => sha256:64df5e2068e389326fc91858380a7a308ceb5943364686ba40427aa4cdbcf57b 7.19kB / 7.19kB                                                                                                                                                0.0s 
 => => sha256:801bfaa63ef2094d770c809815b9e2b9c1194728e5e754ef7bc764030e140cea 2.80MB / 2.80MB                                                                                                                                                2.3s 
 => => sha256:ff5ef8cd80620220d704d7c4edaeb643967001e09ad22e4fa45c58f23228ccae 230B / 230B                                                                                                                                                    0.6s 
 => => sha256:73dee1f700a1347f07a0800704a316f22029d79388e96910ec7b1090fe63876b 3.20MB / 3.20MB                                                                                                                                                1.7s 
 => => extracting sha256:801bfaa63ef2094d770c809815b9e2b9c1194728e5e754ef7bc764030e140cea                                                                                                                                                     0.3s 
 => => extracting sha256:7678dd7631a2820af5d8aec5e27200b7b3f863f1632a524409fecc4acd2e17e5                                                                                                                                                     0.1s 
 => => extracting sha256:4c6139ab40d87d329213433884ea0774ec3d13c9df656ecee4dfe2e29aaa0ef9                                                                                                                                                     0.9s 
 => => extracting sha256:ff5ef8cd80620220d704d7c4edaeb643967001e09ad22e4fa45c58f23228ccae                                                                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => => extracting sha256:73dee1f700a1347f07a0800704a316f22029d79388e96910ec7b1090fe63876b                                                                                                                                                     0.3s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 3.08kB                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.3s 
 => [3/5] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s 
 => [4/5] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                                                 9.9s 
 => [5/5] COPY src/ .                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.1s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.5s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.4s 
 => => writing image sha256:1858c98da32f9bc29088e57312993866b668da33de7fe6d09f470970638e8b7b                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
```

## Result of docker-compose

```
PS D:\Development\KiddoLullaby\app> docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml --verbose build
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: .\docker-compose-dev.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.docker\\config.json', 'C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: C:\Users\jlpfa\.docker\config.json
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.docker\\config.json', 'C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: C:\Users\jlpfa\.docker\config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.parse_auth: Auth data for https://index.docker.io/v1/ is absent. Client might be using a credentials store instead.
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'credsStore' section
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /version HTTP/1.1" 200 None
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.41/version HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.docker_client.get_client: docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
docker-py version: 4.3.1
CPython version: 3.7.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
compose.cli.docker_client.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localnpipe
compose.cli.docker_client.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': 'Docker Engine - Community'}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '20.10.2', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.41', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2020-12-28T16:15:28.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': '8891c58', 'GoVersion': 'go1.13.15', 'KernelVersion': '4.19.128-microsoft-standard', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}, {'Name': 'containerd', 'Version': '1.4.3', 'Details': {'GitCommit': '269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b'}}, {'Name': 'runc', 'Version': '1.0.0-rc92', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff'}}, {'Name': 'docker-init', 'Version': '0.19.0', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'de40ad0'}}], Version=20.10.2, ApiVersion=1.41, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=8891c58, GoVersion=go1.13.15, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.19.128-microsoft-standard, BuildTime=2020-12-28T16:15:28.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('app_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.41/networks/app_default HTTP/1.1" 404 None
compose.service.build: Building kiddoDev
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (path='\\\\?\\D:\\Development\\KiddoLullaby\\app', tag='kiddoLullaby', rm=True, forcerm=False, pull=False, nocache=False, dockerfile=None, cache_from=None, labels=None, buildargs={}, network_mode=None, target=None, shmsize=None, extra_hosts=None, container_limits={'memory': None}, gzip=False, isolation=None, platform=None)
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Looking for auth config
docker.auth._resolve_authconfig_credstore: Looking for auth entry for 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Sending auth config ('https://index.docker.io/v1/', 'index.docker.io')
```

If I logout first...

```
PS D:\Development\KiddoLullaby\app> docker logout
Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
PS D:\Development\KiddoLullaby\app> docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml --verbose build
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: .\docker-compose-dev.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.docker\\config.json', 'C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: C:\Users\jlpfa\.docker\config.json
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.docker\\config.json', 'C:\\Users\\jlpfa\\.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: C:\Users\jlpfa\.docker\config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'credsStore' section
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /version HTTP/1.1" 200 None
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.41/version HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.docker_client.get_client: docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
docker-py version: 4.3.1
CPython version: 3.7.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
compose.cli.docker_client.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localnpipe
compose.cli.docker_client.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': 'Docker Engine - Community'}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '20.10.2', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.41', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2020-12-28T16:15:28.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': '8891c58', 'GoVersion': 'go1.13.15', 'KernelVersion': '4.19.128-microsoft-standard', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}, {'Name': 'containerd', 'Version': '1.4.3', 'Details': {'GitCommit': '269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b'}}, {'Name': 'runc', 'Version': '1.0.0-rc92', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff'}}, {'Name': 'docker-init', 'Version': '0.19.0', 'Details': {'GitCommit': 'de40ad0'}}], Version=20.10.2, ApiVersion=1.41, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=8891c58, GoVersion=go1.13.15, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.19.128-microsoft-standard, BuildTime=2020-12-28T16:15:28.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('app_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.41/networks/app_default HTTP/1.1" 404 None
compose.service.build: Building kiddoDev
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (path='\\\\?\\D:\\Development\\KiddoLullaby\\app', tag='kiddoLullaby', rm=True, forcerm=False, pull=False, nocache=False, dockerfile=None, cache_from=None, labels=None, buildargs={}, network_mode=None, target=None, shmsize=None, extra_hosts=None, container_limits={'memory': None}, gzip=False, isolation=None, platform=None)
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Looking for auth config
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Sending auth config ()
```

and login

```
PS D:\Development\KiddoLullaby> docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: *********
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

same result

Comment: It is unlikely that this has anything to do with large files in your docker context, as they aren't uploaded anywhere (unless they end up in your image, bloating it). This also isn't an image problem, because it hasn't got as far as uploading that. The last line in your compose output is sending your credentials to docker hub, not your build context or image. The problem is in your creds, or in your internet connection, or on Docker's side of the fence.

Comment: Did you know that Docker are limiting/throttling anonymous and free accounts now? Is it possible that you've hit the limits? I think they are 100 pulls/pushes for anonymous and 200 for free accounts, but I could be wrong on the actual numbers.

Comment: If it is 100 in a lifetime... maybe. This month, definitely not.

Comment: I added some details, tried logout and running, it halts on same step. When I login it says succeeded. It still fails.

Comment: Tried creating an auth token and using that. Still the same result.

Comment: Found the free account limits: 200 container image requests per 6 hours

Comment: Have you tried it with a well-formed name for your image? The format is hub_account_name/image_name. So, in your case it should be something like (I guess...) `kidlullaby/kiddoLullaby`, where the first part is your account and the second is  the image name. Btw, you're not building the image with a name in your initial examples, you need to use the `--tag` flag for that. Compose will use the image name you provide. Also, you don't really need compose for a single service, so if it isn't working for you then you could just dump it and move on :)

Comment: I removed the image line in the file and it worked.

Comment: I *think* it was looking for the image on docker hub... I'm not sure why that wouldn't result in finding nothing and then build the image.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Been a while. Removing the image line seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and the problem was solved by just adding `./git` inside `.dockerignore` file.

My `.git/` dir was less than 4Mb, but for some reason it was causing the problem.

compose version: `1.27.4`